# Adding a value to 'datetime' causing an overflow in SQL Server select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a SQL function in SQL Server to convert year-week string into a date as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_ConvertStringToDate
   (@yearWeek VARCHAR)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN DATEADD(WEEK, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@yearWeek, 6, 2)), 
                   DATEADD(YEAR, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@yearWeek, 1, 4)) - 1900, 0))
END
```

And then when I execute the below query:

```
select dbo.f_ConvertStringToDate(yearWeek) 
from dbo.mytab
where year = 2014 and week = 25;
```

`yearWeek` is a string of format `2014-25`. I get an error:

> SQL Error: Adding a value to 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this worked when I changed your definition to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_ConvertStringToDate
(@yearWeek VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN DATEADD(WEEK, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@yearWeek, 6, 2)), DATEADD(YEAR, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@yearWeek, 1, 4)) - 1900, 0))
END
```

Just to note, the way to debug this was to run the SQL without using a function, if you try

```
DECLARE @yearweek VARCHAR; 
SELECT @yearweek = '2014-05'; 
SELECT @yearweek;
```

...then you will see that @yearweek has been set a value of "2" instead of "2014-05".

Comment: As @RichardHansell mentions correctly, "When the length is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1."

Comment: It wasn't about length, in my case, the problem was few dates were "0000-00", hence there was a overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.

When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

So in your case overflow will happen to fix this change `varchar` to `varchar(20)`
[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176089.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you set the length of @yearweek parameter,  must be work

```
alter FUNCTION dbo.f_ConvertStringToDate
(@yearWeek VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN 
RETURN DATEADD(WEEK, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@yearWeek, 6, 2)), DATEADD(YEAR, CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@yearWeek, 1, 4)) - 1900, 0))
END
```